# Evaluate if statements stored in Lua table

Tags: lua

Very much a Lua beginner here.
I would like to store some if statements in a Lua table and return the result of whichever statement matches. EG:

```
table = {
  [1] "if foo == bar1 then result = alice return result end",
  [2] "if foo == bar2 then result = bob return result end"
}
```

How do I iterate over the table and return the result of only the statement that matches? I think I something like below?

```
function get_result(foo, bar1, bar2)
  for k, v in pairs(table) do
    something
  end
end
```

Comment: How are `alice` and `bob` defined? This can be approached with [`load`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-load), but are you sure you want these strings to be Lua code, and not just a string containing the results? Or maybe the table entries could be functions that generate results? (This is possibly some form of an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).)

Comment: Without the iteration this looks like a simple mapping: `table = {[bar1]=alice, [bar2]=bob}` then `table[foo]`. I agree regarding XY here.

Answer (score 3):

The [`load`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-load) function can be used to evaluate arbitrary Lua code, known as a *chunk*.

Its fourth argument can be used to provide the *environment* for the chunk, which gives better control over the *upvalues* present (see: [sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(software_development))).

On success, `load` returns a function. Calling this function *runs* the compiled chunk. You may want to stop any errors in the chunk from propagating to the calling context by using [`pcall`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-pcall).

On syntax error, `load` returns `nil` and an error message.

In this example, `'alice'` and `'bob'` are strings. They could also be defined within the environment table (`alice = ...`) to enable the validity of `return alice` from your example.

```
local function get_result(foo, bar1, bar2)
    local evals = {
        "if foo == bar1 then return 'alice' end",
        "if foo == bar2 then return 'bob' end"
    }

    for index, code in ipairs(evals) do
        local chunk, err = load(code, tostring(index), "t", {
            foo = foo,
            bar1 = bar1,
            bar2 = bar2
        })

        if chunk then
            local status, result = pcall(chunk)

            if status and result then
                print(result)
            end
        else
            error(err)
        end
    end
end

get_result("a", "a", "b")
print("------")
get_result("b", "a", "b")
```

Output:

```
alice
------
bob
```

---

If the above seems like an unwieldy way to yield one of two (or more) values, then you are probably experiencing an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

You may instead be looking for a simple lookup table (cheers to [@Aki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4567755/aki)).

The following example achieves the same results as the previous:

```
local function get_result(foo, bar1, bar2)
    local lookup = {
        [bar1] = "alice",
        [bar2] = "bob"
    }

    local result = lookup[foo]

    if result then
        print(result)
    end
end

get_result("a", "a", "b")
print("------")
get_result("b", "a", "b")
```

Output:

```
alice
------
bob
```

Answer (score 0):

OK - I played around with it and my Solution is...

```
€ cat alicebob.lua 
-- alicebob.lua -- Lua 5.4
local table = { -- Dont redefine the global table Library ;-)
  [1] = [[foo = foo == 'bar1' and 'Alice']],
  [2] = [[foo = foo == 'bar2' and 'Bob']]
}

-- Let load() be a method for Datatype String
string.load = load

-- Define global foo for Alice
foo = 'bar1'
table[1]:load()()
print(foo)
-- Should print: Alice
-- Now set foo to do above for Bob
foo = 'bar2'
table[2]:load()()
print(foo)
-- clean up for collectgarbage()
string.load = nil
foo = nil
-- End of alicebob.lua
€ lua alicebob.lua
Alice
Bob
```